# Allow lambdas with mustache on command line?

Tags: ruby, mustache

If I try to use ruby lambdas in my YAML frontmatter with command line mustache, it is treated as if it was straight text.

E.g. test.yaml:

```
name: Willy  
wrapped: proc { |text| "<b>#{text}</b>" }
```

template.mustache:

```
{{#wrapped}}
{{name}} is awesome.
{{/wrapped}}
```

Result on the command line:

```
$ mustache test.yaml template.mustache  
Willy is awesome.
```

On the other hand, in IRB:

```
irb(main):032:0> Mustache.render("{{#wrapped}}{{name}} is awesome.  
{{/wrapped}}", name: "Willy", wrapped: proc {|text| "<b>#{text}</b>"  
})

=> "<b>Willy is awesome.</b>"
```

Can I get the same result from the command line as when I use mustache from IRB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I get the same result from the command line as when I use mustache from IRB?

No, you cannot.

The reason you get different results is that in IRB you pass *a ruby hash object*, having two keys. The key `:wrapped` *is an instance of `proc`*.

In YAML, OTOH, you have both values *as strings*. YAML has a very limited support of storing objects and I am not aware of any extension allowing the serialization of `proc`s. The naïve attempt does not work:

```
{wrapped: proc { |text| "<b>#{text}</b>" }}.to_yaml
#⇒ "---\n:wrapped: !ruby/object:Proc {}\n"
```

Obviously, when loaded back, this will become a NOOP. You might hack this behaviour with something like:

```
YAML.load_file('/path/to/your/file.yaml').
  map { |k, v| [k, v.start_with?('proc') ? eval(v) : v] }.
  to_h[:wrapped].('Hi!')
#⇒ "<b>Hi!</b>"
```

But I would strongly suggest not to do that.

Comment: While this is correct (although I have used the second implementation in some internal libraries where I had full and total control of the yml files). [This article](https://yehudakatz.com/2011/11/19/how-to-marshal-procs-using-rubinius/) on how it can be done in rubinius makes for an interesting read.